# Passing a dictionary to threaded function in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

So, I have a function explain(item) that takes 1 argument. This argument is intended to be a dictionary with 8-9 keys. When I call `explain(item)` everything is fine. But when I call (items is the same variable)

```
threads.append(threading.Thread(target = explain, args=(item)))
threads[i].start()
threads[i].join()
```

I get errors like this one:

```
Exception in thread Thread-72:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: explain() takes exactly 1 argument (10 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)` should probably be `self.__target(self.__args, self.__kwargs)`. Otherwise you are passing every item in the dictionary as an argument.

Comment: The `self.__target` call is coming from the source for the threading module, definitely not where the problem is!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like you are intending to pass a one-item tuple as the `args` parameter to `threading.Thread()` but using `args=(item)` is equivalent to `args=item`.  You need to add a comma to create a tuple, so it would be `args=(item,)`:

```
threads.append(threading.Thread(target = explain, args=(item,))).
```

Without the trailing comma the parentheses are just a method for grouping an expression, for example:

```
>>> (100)  # this is just the value 100
100
>>> (100,) # this is a one-element tuple that contains 100
(100,)
```